# Dispalying image in android

Tags: android

I am trying to display an image in android.The process is i am downloading 1 image from net and trying to display it in the screen,the problem i am facing is in the activity screen i cant able to set the content view and the image.Following is the code:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Screen:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.);---->Here i cant set as main

        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(
                "http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg");
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.);  //here i cant set the image id
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your project.sometimes it don't take R.java file.

Answer (score 3):

Use Android Smart Image View. That is the easiest way to display an image using a URL. Here is the [link](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/).

Comment: any living tutorial ? I can't get it work from this URL http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the project using Project -> Clean. If it still exists, run the project, and they will usually disappear.

Comment: I cleaned the project and ran but it shows fix the problem in your project before running it.

Comment: Is it? You keep getting such errors frequently in Android. Try restarting eclipse, or creating a new project and then pasting. Hey try clicking Ctrl + Shift + o and your errors may be resolved